# Stuck on "Update Pending" when trying to install an extension, or update Magento version, M2 2.2.1

Tags: upgrade, magento2.2.2, magento-2.2.1

I'm using Magento 2.2.1, and I've been trying to install an extension, and I've tried to do that from Web Setup Wizard, but when I select my extension to install, and do the check before installing it, I get a dependency error, I try again a few times, and the third time doesn't give any dependency error anymore. I proceed, but then it gets stuck on Update Pending, with the console log saying this:

```
[2018-02-21 21:49:39 UTC] Job "setup:maintenance:enable []" has started
Enabled maintenance mode

[2018-02-21 21:49:39 UTC] Job "setup:maintenance:enable []" has been 
successfully completed
[2018-02-21 21:49:39 UTC] Job "setup:cache:disable []" has started
Changed cache status:
config: 1 -> 0
layout: 1 -> 0
block_html: 1 -> 0
collections: 1 -> 0
reflection: 1 -> 0
db_ddl: 1 -> 0
eav: 1 -> 0
customer_notification: 1 -> 0
full_page: 1 -> 0
config_integration: 1 -> 0
config_integration_api: 1 -> 0
translate: 1 -> 0
config_webservice: 1 -> 0

[2018-02-21 21:49:39 UTC] Job "setup:cache:disable []" has been successfully 
completed
```

I though it might be something about the extension, but then I've tried to do a Magento version upgrade, from 2.2.1 to 2.2.2, from System Upgrade, and I get stuck on the same point, with the same error.. Any ideas?

Comment: I faced this issue dozens of time, for installing and uninstalling. Every time it's a different solution. One time I had file write permissions issue, the other time I had to clear cache and re-run cron (some times cron needs to be updated for some reason), one time it was my server's max execution time limit (this was happening during the backup that kept failing). This has started to be Voodoo business for me.

Comment: Now I' m facing this error: Process extensions Status:
Update application is not running
When I open Magento Update Page